# Combinatorics question about alternately-coloured diagonal halves of sides of a cube

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, puzzle, combinatorial-geometry

Diagonal halves of each side of a cube are painted in alternate colours. Let the vertex at which such a half forms a right angle be its *base vertex*. What is the minimum number and the maximum number possible of *common* base vertices of three halves of the same colour?

Comment: very confusing. I don't understand the question. Maybe try some illustrations or examples to clarify.

Comment: There are only two colors, correct?

Comment: @Tad yes, that's correct.

Comment: @JLee feel free to ask me anything about the question. which part is most confusing to you?

Comment: What does a diagonal half of a cube look like? Also, when "such a half forms a right angle" with what? Also, three halves of the same color? huh? please use pictures.

Comment: @JLee (1) Diagonal halves of each _side_ of a cube. Obviously, the side of a cube is a square. Diagonal halves of a _square_, then, would be either side of the diagonal of the square. (2) Clearly these halves are triangular, and one of their angles is a right angle.

Comment: @JLee (3) The diagonal could be in one of two orientations, and for each orientation there are two possible colourings. So there are 4 possible states for any side of the cube. Now clearly there are 3 sides of the cube around any of its vertices. Assuming all sides of the cube have been divided and coloured, there can be [a maximum of 3 such diagonal halves](http://domathtogether.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Screenshot-2012-11-24-132703.png) around any vertex. There may be lesser, of course, if one or more of those previously-described diagonals end at that vertex.

Comment: @JLee (4) I'm afraid I haven't found an accurate illustration for this question yet. If you have a helpful visual aid and want to add it to the question, be my guest.

Comment: I'll try to simplify the question even further, for anybody who finds it lacking in explanation.

1. Consider all possible combinations of the 4 different states for each side of the cube. In some (perhaps all?) of these there must be at least one such vertex that is a base vertex of all of the 3 sides around it (i.e., it has 3 diagonal halves around it) and _all 3 of these halves_ turn out to be coloured the same.

Comment: 2. Can we find _multiple_ such vertices on a cube? In fact, can we have _all 8 of the vertices_ be common base vertices for 3 equichromatic halves? If not, what is the maximum number we can have?

Comment: 3. Similarly consider the minimum number. Is it 0, i.e., does there exist a combination in which there are no such vertices? Or do we instead find at least one such vertex in _every_ possible combination? (This is equivalent to asking if the set of all combinations containing at least one vertex which fulfills these criteria is a proper subset of the set of all possible combinations or not.) If it is not 0, what is the minimum?

Comment: Thank you. Great explanation. I was missing the word "side", as you pointed out. Very interesting question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $4^6$=4,096 possible different cubes, ignoring any duplicates that are due to orientation or reflection. I was going to simply have a program loop through each of them and count the common base vertices of 3 halves of the same color, but before I could do that, I realized that the minimum number of base vertices is 0, as in the example below,

[image]

and, when you force the constraint that each side of the cube MUST have 2 different colors, then the maximum number of common base vertices of 3 halves of the same color is 2, as in the example below

[image]

The red circles mark the common base vertices of 3 halves of the same color. Why can't we have more than 2? Because of the alternate coloring constraint. The 2 base vertices circled in orange and green can never be the same color. (Note, the bottom green circle is referring only to the upper box for this point.)

---

EDIT: Another way to think about it:
If we remove the coloring constraint, and each triangle could be the same color, then all 8 points would be a common base vertex with 3 identical colors.

However, let's say we then introduce the rule that each side must contain both colors. As you create a cube with one of the vertices all the same color, you must realize that you are also forcing the other color to be part of the adjacent group of three vertices, and only one of those remaining 3 groups can contain triangles all of the same color.

For example, take the top right red circle in the picture. Let's say that that you set those three halves to blue to create your first group of 3. In doing this, you are forcing one member of each of the 3 adjacent groups to be white (top orange circle, bottom red circle, and top green circle). Since there are 12 triangles total, you might first think (as I did) that there are at most 4 groups of three with each group having the same color, but achieving this is not possible because the two colors circled in orange will always be different, because of the coloring constraint. Same thing for green.

In other words, you can choose a corner to give 3 identical colors to, and then you may choose a 2nd corner to give three identical colors to, but in choosing the second corner, you guarantee that the remaining 2 corners cannot ever have 3 triangles of the same color.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your results are entirely correct – 0 and 2 are indeed the minimum and maximum. I'll accept it as it is, but can you perhaps expand on your reasoning for determining that 2 is the maximum number?

Comment: Sure- I'll do my best.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, great answer.